# Same Keras model got different result between Ubuntu and windows?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, training-data

I want to use my linux computer to train the model.
I directly load the pre-training model in windows, but the loss get higher and the accuracy declined.

this is my training model

```
def create_model(self):
    print("CREATE NEW MODEL")
    input_img = Input(shape=(nb_features,))

    selection = Dense(64, activation='relu')(input_img)
    selection = Dropout(0.20)(selection)
    selection = Dense(32, activation='relu')(selection)
    selection_out1 = Dropout(0.20)(selection)
    selection_out2 = Dense(nb_class)(selection_out1)
    selection_out3 = Activation("softmax")(selection_out2)

    self.model_1 = Model(input=input_img, output=selection_out1)
    self.model_2 = Model(input=input_img, output=selection_out2)
    # construct the selection model 
    self.model_3 = Model(input=input_img, output=selection_out3)
    # compile autoencoder
    self.model_3.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

def save_model(self, num=0):
    if num == -1:
        self.model_1.save("./model/model_1_")
        self.model_2.save("./model/model_2_")
        self.model_3.save("./model/model_3_")
    else:
        self.model_1.save("./model/model_1_" + str(num))
        self.model_2.save("./model/model_2_" + str(num))
        self.model_3.save("./model/model_3_" + str(num))
```

this is my output

```
Ubuntu
Epoch 193/200
6375/6375 [==============================] - 0s 14us/step - loss: 0.0188 - 
acc: 0.9936
Epoch 194/200
6375/6375 [==============================] - 0s 14us/step - loss: 0.0151 - 
acc: 0.9956

Windows
Epoch 193/200
6375/6375 [==============================] - 0s 17us/step - loss: 0.0043 - 
acc: 0.9995
Epoch 194/200
6375/6375 [==============================] - 0s 17us/step - loss: 0.0019 - 
acc: 0.9997
```

Ubuntu seems always have some uneliminated error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there may be differences in your `tensorflow`, `keras`, or `numpy` versions between the two systems. If those are not the same, the issue is most likely because of small differences in the implementations between versions, not differences in ubuntu and windows.

With the given that your versions are the same:

All because your model architecture is the same doesn't mean it's going to get the same results.

Before any training starts each layer needs to initialize some weights to start out with. Generally the default initialization function is `glorot_uniform`, which draws samples randomly from a uniform distribution within a certain range.

Additionally `Dropout` layers turn off random neurons during training which will also adds some more variance in how your model will perform in different training sessions.

The difference you're seeing isn't ubuntu vs windows but rather different initial weights and `Dropout` turning off different neurons during training.

Comment: Hi, thanks your reply. But I can get the same training result in windows the result always convergence. but the Ubuntu can not. I have tried removing the dropout, the Ubuntu still get worse result

Comment: How many times have you tried this? And what does "result always convergence" mean? As your loss is decreasing your neural network is converging. Do you mean that the windows and linux aren't converging?

Comment: I know there is variation everytime. In my windows system I tried about 5 times can get the same similar result. (accuracy converging to 0.9995 ~ 1) My linux system always accuracy always stuck in 0.990~0.995

Comment: are your keras and tensorflow and numpy versions the same on both systems?

Comment: Oh thanks, I update to the same version, It seems work now. my windows tensorflow is 1.12.0, and my linux is 1.11.0.

Comment: Yay! Good luck on your future neural network endeavors :)

Comment: I have identical environments made from the same yml file and am having this problem. The linux model is always subpar with an F1 score in the .5 range while the windows model is around .93. I understand they are initialized with different values and therefore follow different paths but the results should not be consistently different every time. The code and data is identical. These results seem to go beyond initial seeding